# SimpleCart.js - checkout cart buttons do not work when inside slide-out panel

Tags: jquery, e-commerce

Live site example is [here](http://www.rubytuesdaycreative.co.uk/testsite/snood.html)
I managed to get the checkout button working just fine within my normal page content (you can see it underneath the picture, although the link is white at the moment as this is just a placeholder)

However I have a slide-out div that will contain the basket data, and will have the checkout code. The code is:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_checkout"></a>
```

For some reason, none of the links in my `slide-out-div` work, I am assuming there is something that the simplecart is interfering with being inside a hidden div? The div is on the page:

```
<!-- Checkout cart div -->
<div class="slide-out-div">
    <a class="handle" href="http://link-for-non-js-users">Content</a>
    <div class="simpleCart_items"></div>
<a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_empty emptyBtn">Empty</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_checkout buyBtn">Checkout</a>
</div>
```

Any data in this div do not seem to interact as they should do.